# Crontab - vim preferences

Tags: vim, cron

I use vim as my normal edito and so have my vimrc set up in a particular way.

I quite often find myself editing crons with the command

```
crontab -e
```

When I do, I edit in vim, but without my normal vimrc - I could load it with a command but I'd like to have it load up automatically - what am I missing?

Extra information - I'm a user on the system, I don't have admin rights....

Comment: Can you please clarify, the issue is that the `vimrc` is not loading, not that the default editor is incorrect - right?  It appears to me as though it's the `vimrc` issue, not the editor issue as people are suggesting.

Comment: It works on my system. Add some details such as OS, shell, contents of $EDITOR and vim version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me like everyone is missing the issue, the issue appears to be that your `vimrc` file is not working when you use `crontab -e`, for example.  Assuming that is correct:

You probably have `~\.vimrc` configured for the user, but not the system.  You could copy/create a global one (that should work for vim wherever).

Typically, the global `vimrc` is:

```
/etc/vim/vimrc
```

-or-

```
/usr/local/share/vim/vimrc
```

Depending on your *Nix based system.

Hopefully that is a bit more on what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your vim settings should be enabled system-wide for this to work, as `crontab(1)` calls EDITOR without enviroment.

Comment: This is accurate, but it may be helpful to give a fix as well.  It is more fitting of the SU format.  Just a thought.

Comment: @nerdwaller Duly noted. Thanks. Is it good practice to remove an unproper answer?

Comment: I'm not a moderator, so I can't really say the best practice.  I tend to add to/edit mine, or if I was way off delete it to remove clutter.  But the best place to ask/search for answers to questions about SU is [Meta](http://meta.superuser.com).  Like I said before, you're accurate - it just helps to have a solution as well.  That's basically my personal criteria before up-voting.